# Display parent terms in yoast BREADCRUMBS on product page woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, breadcrumbs, yoast

I have spent hours to find a solution but couldn't

Does anyone know how to append parent terms in yoast breadcrumbs?

Current situation - I have assigend a child term taxonomy to the product and I see the breadcrumb like this below.

Home > Shop > child taxonomy name

If there are parents, it should look like this below:

Home > Shop > Parent > Child name

If there are more parents in hierarchy, then like this below

Home > Shop > Parent 1 > Parent 2 > child term.

I want to add the above described functionality to this if condition code below. The below code appends a custom page in the breadcrumb trail. Now the next thing is to append parent terms before the last child term.

```
/**
 * Conditionally Override Yoast SEO Breadcrumb Trail
 * http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/wordpress-seo/trunk/frontend/class-breadcrumbs.php
 */

add_filter( 'wpseo_breadcrumb_links', 'wpse_100012_override_yoast_breadcrumb_trail' );

function wpse_100012_override_yoast_breadcrumb_trail( $links ) {
    global $post;

    if ( is_singular( 'product' )) {
        $breadcrumb[] = array(
            'url' => get_permalink(14653),
            'text' => 'Subjects',
        );

        array_splice( $links, 2, -2, $breadcrumb );
    }

    return $links;
}
```